# Enabled property of ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Below is my ASP.Net markup:

```
<div>
        <asp:ListBox ID="listSourceBox" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlDataSource" SelectionMode="Multiple"
            Enabled="false" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="Id"></asp:ListBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSourceToDest" Text="&gt;&gt;" runat="server" OnClick="btnSourceToDest_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnDestToSource" Text="&lt;&lt;" runat="server" OnClick="btnDestToSource_Click" />

        <asp:ListBox ID="listDestBox" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:ListBox>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings: Movies %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT Id, Title FROM Movies"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
```

Both the *listSourceBox* and *listDestBox* is disabled. When I run my application, it throws "Object reference not set to an instance of object" mainly due to *listSourceBox* is disabled. However, when I  enabled *listSourceBox*, everything works fine, ideally, *listDestBox* should be disabled, but its not !! Also, When *Enabled = false* should disable the ListBox like all other ASP .Net controls, but it behaves differently. Why?

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ASP Listbox` doesn't respects the `Enabled` property, you need to do that explicitly in code behind like this:-

```
listSourceBox.Attributes.Add("disabled","");
listSourceBox.Attributes.Remove("disabled");
```

Although, this has nothing to do with your `Object Reference error`, Since that is just an attribute, there is something else wrong in your code.

**Edit:**
If you are targetting ASP.NET 4.0, Controls that are not designed to take user input will not respect this property, so you need to include following within the `<system.web>` section of your web.config file:-

```
<system.web>
     <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5">.
</system.web>
```

After this you can simple use `Enabled`property like this:-

```
listSourceBox.Enabled = true;
listSourceBox.Enabled = false;
```

Or in the mark-up like this:-

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="listSourceBox" runat="server" Enabled="false"...
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. From whatever I have read, when Enabled=false, the listbox doesn't get rendered. This could be causing the issue. When I Enable the listBox, it works fine. Hence, the Enabled property should be causing this. Anyways, since it doesn't respect the Enabled property, I'll look for other ways (like the one you mentioned).

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal - Yup, but I had a doubt and I have tested it myself, for me when I am setting `Enabled=false`, its not disabling the control but still its rendering properly that's why I said, there must be something else. Also, I have updated for ASP.NET 4.0 please check, and let me know if that helped!

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal - Let me know if that helped. If it did do accept it as answer :)

Comment: Sorry for getting back late Rahul. Sure it did help. Thanks!